# Focusable not working for textfield in SwiftUI in tvOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, focus, tvos

I am working on a tvOS app with SwiftUI. I have black as theme colour. When my textfield is in focus I want text colour to be black and when field is not in focus I want my text colour to be white.
I am trying to use focusable method but it is not working. When running on simulator and the respective fields are in focus, it does not log anything in the debug console.

```
@State private var isEmailFieldInFocus: Bool = false
@State private var isPasswordFieldInFocus: Bool = false
```

```
ZStack {
   Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
       TextField("", text: self.$emailAddress)
          .foregroundColor(self.isEmailFieldInFocus ? Color.black : Color.white)
          .border(self.isEmailFieldInFocus ? Color.clear : Color.white, width: 1)
          .focusable(true) { (focus) in
             self.isEmailFieldInFocus = focus
             if focus {
                print("Email field is in focus")
             }
        }
                
        TextField("", text: self.$password)
           .foregroundColor(self.isPasswordFieldInFocus ? Color.black : Color.white)
           .border(self.isPasswordFieldInFocus ? Color.clear : Color.white, width: 1)
           .focusable(true) { (focus) in
              self.isPasswordFieldInFocus = focus
              if focus {
                 print("Password field is in focus")
              }
         }
     }   
}
```

Comment: `focusable` is to make focus-tracking for non-focusable views, TextField is focusable by-nature, so this modifier is not for it.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the desired output ?